# Adding a label or text for added textbox from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Sorry if it was discussed before but all of them doesn't work for me. How to add a label or a text, just like adding a textbox? It suppose to be looks like the first textbox.

Here's my html code

```html
<label for="color" class="control-label col-xs-4"><p class="left">Color/s</p></label>
 <div class="col-xs-7">
            
<input name="color" class="req" id="theValue" autocomplete = "off" />
  <p><a href="javascript:addElement()" >Add Color</a></p>       
 <div id="myDiv"></div>
 <div style='clear: both;'></div>
```

and here's the javascript for adding textbox

```js
 <script language=javascript>
        function addElement() {
        var ni = document.getElementById('myDiv');
        var numi = document.getElementById('theValue');
        var num = (document.getElementById('theValue').value -1 + 2);
        numi.value = num;
        var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
        var divIdName = 'my'+num+'Div';
        newdiv.setAttribute('id',divIdName);
        newdiv.innerHTML = '<input type=text id=' + num + ' ' + num + ' class= "req"><a href="javascript:remove('+divIdName+')">Remove</a>';
        ni.appendChild(newdiv);
        }


        function remove(dId) {
        var ni = document.getElementById('myDiv');
        ni.removeChild(dId);
        }

        </script>
```

Image below for better understanding

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about that is what you expected, but try something like that:

```
 <script language=javascript>
    function addElement() {
    var ni = document.getElementById('myDiv');
    var numi = document.getElementById('theValue');
    var num = (document.getElementById('theValue').value -1 + 2);


    numi.value = num;
    var divIdName = 'my'+num+'Div';
    var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
    var column = document.createElement('div');
    var label = document.createElement('label');
    var remove = document.createElement('a');
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    column.setAttribute('class', 'col-xs-7');
    input.setAttribute('type','text');
    input.setAttribute('id',  num + ' ' + num  )
    remove.setAttribute('href','javascript:remove('+divIdName+')');
    remove.innerHTML = 'Remove';
    label.innerHTML = 'text';
    label.setAttribute('for',  num + ' ' + num );

    newdiv.setAttribute('id',divIdName);


    ni.appendChild(newdiv);

    newdiv.appendChild(label);
    newdiv.appendChild(column);
    column.appendChild(input);
    column.appendChild(remove)
    }


    function remove(dId) {
    var ni = document.getElementById('myDiv');
    ni.removeChild(dId);
    }

    </script>
```

Comment: As you can see on my image, in the added textbox there's no "color" label on it, that's my problem :(

Answer (score 0):

If your question was about why your label for the input element isn't working:

You need to give the input element an id, "color" in this case.

Syntax

```
<label for="element_id">label</label>
```

Comment: As you can see on my image, in the added textbox there's no "color" label on it, that's my problem :(

Comment: Do you mean the "Add Color" text under the first input element?